# MarkLogic: Using xdmp:estimate and coding standards

Tags: indexing, marklogic

I had initially written the  query:

```
cts:search(fn:doc(),cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("ts:week"), ">=", xs:date("2009-05-01")),"unfiltered")
```

I modified it to the following, as it seemed more aesthetic:

```
let $range_query := cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("ts:week"), ">=", xs:date("2009-05-01"))
let $query := cts:search(fn:doc(), $range_query, "unfiltered")
return $query
```

I got the same results as expected.

Now, just to get confirm my "unfiltered" approach I ran the fn:count vs xdmp:estimate check.

```
xdmp:estimate(cts:search(fn:doc(),cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("ts:week"), ">=", xs:date("2009-05-01")))
```

The above query ran fine and returned the expected result.

But,

```
let $range_query := cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("ts:week"), ">=", xs:date("2009-05-01"))
let $query := cts:search(fn:doc(), $range_query)
return xdmp:estimate($query)
```

Gave me an error: Expression is unsearchable.

1) Is my approach using let and return the recommended way of writing code in MarkLogic ?

2) What makes the expression unsearchable using the let and return approach ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xdmp:estimate` function takes an expression for evaluation. You can't pass a variable.  The `$query` in your case at the third line is holding a sequence of results, and you can't estimate a sequence.

In fact your `$query` should really be called `$results` because it's not holding a query, it's holding the executed results of the search.

Think of `xdmp:estimate` as saying, "Hey if I ran this expression how many results do the indexes think I'd get?"

Comment: I put the search expression in xdmp:estimate, it works fine. Thanks.